# consequence of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Let $f$  a continuous function on $[a, b]$  $a < b$ ,derivable on $(a, b)$   then there exist  $c_1, c_2 \in (a, b)$ ,$c_1 \ne c_2$ such that $\frac{f (b) - f (a)}{b - a} = \frac{f '(c1) + f' (c2)}{2}$

I tried to construct a function as the proof of MVT but i stuck some help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $m=(a+b)/2$ be the midpoint. Then we can write $$f'(c_1)=2\frac{f(m)-f(a)}{b-a},\;\;f'(c_2)=2\frac{f(b)-f(m)}{b-a}$$ so $$\frac{f'(c_1)+f'(c_2)}{2}=\frac{(f(m)-f(a))+(f(b)-f(m))}{b-a}=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$ where $c_1\in (a,m),\;c_2\in (m,b)$.